# Find rank in SQL table

Tags: t-sql

I have a test table

```
ID  V_ID
1    1
1    2
```

I want max(V_ID) and resulr should be V_ID 2

```
select Id,max(V_ID) from test
    group by Id,value
```

I am trying simple query but it's still pulling two records. Is there any other simple query 1) we can try rank 2)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be grouping only by the `ID` column:

```
SELECT ID, MAX(V_ID)
FROM test
GROUP BY IdD;
```

A more general pattern for this type of problem uses `ROW_NUMBER` to find the entire record for each `Id` having the max value of `V_ID`:

```
SELECT ID, V_ID
FROM
(
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY V_ID DESC) rn
    FROM test
) t
WHERE rn = 1;
```